# HAproxy web server redirects

Tags: haproxy

I have only one PUBLIC IP address and two web servers one for each site I run. I have been trying to setup an HAproxy to redirect the requests to the correct web server, as following:

If user calls www.domain1.com, the HA proxy send this request to internal IP 192.168.0.249

If user calls www.domain2.com, it will be redirect to internal IP 192.168.0.100

I have made some searches on the Internet and I have made the following configuration for HAProxy.

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    maxconn 2000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option  redispatch
    timeout connect   5000
    timeout client   10000
    timeout server   10000

#stats
    listen StatServer 0.0.0.0:80
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats usi /haproxy?stats
    stats reaml Strictly\ Private
    stats auth user:pass

frontend http-in
    bind                *:80
    default_backend     domain1
    reqadd              X-forwarded-Proto:\ http
    acl req_dimain2 hdr_beg(host) -i www.domain2.com
    acl req_domain2 hdr_beg(host) -i domain2.com                                                                                                  

    use_backend domain2 if req_domain2

backend domain2
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httplog
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    cookie JSSESIONID prefix
    option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
    server domain2 192.168.0.249 cookie avi_cr weight 1 maxconn 2000 check port 80 inter 2000 rise 2 fall 2

backend dimain1
    mode     http
    balance  roundrobin
    option   httplog
    option   httpclose
    option   forwardfor
    cookie   JESSESSIONID prefix
    option   httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
    server   domain1 192.168.0.100 cookie atc_srv weight 1 maxconn 2000 check port 80 inter 2000 rise 2 fall 2
```

On haproxy stats page I always have both domain1 and domain2 DOWN and pages got error 503. Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Marcio

Answer (score 0):

503 Error means HAproxy server didn't get proper web server.You can check on HAproxy front-end part.